# How to pick text form a site and compare it in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am new to selenium. I want to pick text from site and compare in selenium..

Trying the following
 code..

`String msg = driver.get(don't see get text option here)` ? 
Can someone share the code how I can pick the text (such as error message or success message on website)

I know after picking the text I can compare using

```
assertEquals( msg, " text to compare")
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an example web page? Maybe a small dummy, show us some html code or a link to such a page. The situation is just not clear enough. And in the current state your question is very broad. Have you looked at Seleniums documentation? I'm sure they cover such things in their basic beginner examples.

Comment: `driver.get()` is used to go to an URL. You'll have to use something like this to grab the text: `driver.findElement(By.id("message")).getText();` .  Also, if you are new to something, I'd suggest reading the official [documentation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) first[RTFM]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Java, but I've used the selenium c# library extensively, and they look very similar. You can use the "get" method like so (in c#):

```
var infoDiv = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='article-classification']"));
String myText = infoDiv.Text;
```

Then you can do your test against the resulting "myText". The By class allows you to find an element using differents means: XPath, Id, CSS,.... Check [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html) for a list of methods in the Java library.